# ld: library not found for -lpython3.6m

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, clang, cocoapods

I m using starcore_for_ios to run python scripts.

**What i m doing is:**

```
flutter clean
export STARCORE_PATH='/Users/brijeshlakkad'
export STARCORE_PYTHONVERSION='3.6'
export STARCORE_PYTHONLIBRARY='star_python36,python3.6m'
flutter build ios --no-codesign
```

and **i am getting this error:**
when i run `flutter build ios --no-codesign`

```
Xcode's output:
↳
    === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===
    ld: warning: directory not found for option
    '-L/Users/brijeshlakkad/starcore_for_ios/python.files/python-3.6'
    ld: library not found for -lpython3.6m
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
    invocation)
    ld: warning: directory not found for option
    '-L/Users/brijeshlakkad/starcore_for_ios/python.files/python-3.6'
    ld: library not found for -lpython3.6m
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
    invocation)

Encountered error while building for device.
 2.9s
```

Python version: _**3.6.5_1**_
flutter version: 1.0.0

What i have done:
1. Build Active Architecture Only : YES
and
2. Targets >>  Build Settings >> Linking >> Other Linker Flags: $(inherited)

**As you can see error below**

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Why duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53695468/i-have-problem-in-linking-with-python-files-in-starcore-for-ios-directory ?

Comment: Pardon me, it's deleted now